# back navigation bar doesn't hides on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, back, backbarbuttonitem

I need to hide backBarButton, so I am using

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
}
```

its okay on IOS 7 iPhone 4s, but on iPhone 6 iOS 8 this button doesn't hide, there is just "Back" title(without small arrow) and it is unusable. How I can hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select the navigation bar go to attribute inspector and remove the content of back button text box.